# password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"

Tags: django, postgresql, digital-ocean

I am trying to host my website on digitaloceans. on running

```
python manage.py makeigrations
```

I get these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 290, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"

(venv) djangoadmin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~/pyapps/pilgrimage_church$ sudo nano .env 
[sudo] password for djangoadmin: 
(venv) djangoadmin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~/pyapps/pilgrimage_church$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 101, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 290, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/djangoadmin/pyapps/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "djangoadmin"
```

djangoadmin is not in my database at all. I am using Postgresql as my database
However, django admin is an ssh user.

Django database settings:

```
DATABASES = { 'default': 
{ 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', 
  'NAME': env.str('NAME'), 
  'USER': env.str('USER'), 
  'PASSWORD': env.str('PASSWORD'), 
  'HOST': 'localhost', 
  'PORT': '5432', } }
```

What can I do please? I have reset the password. I have dropped and created a new table. I keep getting this error

Comment: What are you database settings in Django? Somewhere you are introducing `djangoadmin` as the connection database user.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver                                                                                                                                DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': env.str('NAME'),
        'USER': env.str('USER'),
        'PASSWORD': env.str('PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
 'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

Comment: This `'USER': env.str('USER'),` is your problem. You are picking up the OS(system) user not the database user. Or set the `PGUSER` env variable to the database user wherever you are doing the migration and use that. For more info on Postgres env variables see [ENV](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html).

Comment: Thanks. I changed the USER to DB_USER and it works fine now